# Data capture from optical mark reader in java

Tags: java

i need to develop software for data capture optical mark reader sheet .please suggest me how to develop and if any third party jar is available help me

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: -1 You'll get more help if your question is more descriptive.  Not many people are likely to go trying to work out what a "data capture optical mark reader sheet" is to help you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a specific optical mark reader device (do you already know what brand and model the device is)? Then the first place to ask is the manufacturer of the device, for how you can program for it, or how you can receive data from the device. If you're lucky the manufacturer has an API or a library that you can use. If you're really lucky the manufacturer has a library in Java.

If you want good answers, tell us more details.

Comment: Not sure why the answer was down-voted. It is legitimate, considering the amount of information (none) provided in the question.